# Leaflet Routing Machine: How do you implement L.Routing.OSRMv1.extend for custom routes?

Tags: leaflet, open-source-routing-machine

I'd like to change the Latitude and Longitude which make up a route.

For example I have **point A** and **point B** the routing machine will create the coordinates and generate the details for the itinerary in between those points, creating a route.

I'd like to change all the coordinates/points in-between point A and point B, thus creating a custom route. And creating a itinerary based on it.

This is the how the `L.Routing.OSRMv1.extend` can be created with a customCallback, I just don't know how to integrate it....

```
const customCallback = (callback) => (context, error, routes) => {
  for (const route of routes) {
    route.coordinates = [...route.coordinates, L.latLng(12.33, 49.6753)];
  }

  callback(context, error, routes);
};

const router = L.Routing.OSRMv1.extend({
  initialize: function (options) {
    L.Routing.OSRMv1.prototype.initialize.call(this, options);
  },

  route: function (waypoints, callback, context, options) {
    const originalCallback = options.callback;
    L.Routing.OSRMv1.prototype.route.call(waypoints, customCallback(originalCallback), this, options);
  }
});
```

The Routing control:

```
const routingControl = L.Routing.control({
  addWaypoints: false,
  collapsible: true,
  createMarker: function (i, wp, nWps) {
    ....
  },
  draggableWaypoints: true,
  fitSelectedRoutes: true,
  geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(),
  lineOptions: {...},
  show: true,
  showAlternatives: false,
  waypoints
}).addTo(map)


router();
```

Executing router yields:

> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Anyone have an idea how to integrate your own coordinates in a route?

Comment: In what way is this question different from previous two: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/435129/leaflet-routing-machine-how-to-add-my-own-data-between-starting-and-end-point-i and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/435217/leaflet-routing-machine-how-to-edit-a-route-before-rendering? Either delete previous two or this one and edit one of the previous ones.

Comment: Just add the waypoints to the function.

Comment: waypoints: [L.latLng(40, -76),L.latLng(41, -74.5),L.latLng(41, -75),]

Comment: @ziggy Where???

Comment: @TomazicM Not the same if you read them.

Comment: Not the same, true, but about the same thing in a different way.

Comment: @TomazicM I deleted them as now I'm getting tracktion.

Comment: `routing = L.Routing.control({waypoints: [L.latLng(40, -76),L.latLng(41, -74.5),L.latLng(41, -75),],position: 'topleft',units: 'imperial',router: L.Routing.mapbox(mapboxApiKey),geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.mapbox({apiKey: mapboxApiKey }),}).addTo(map)`